# Vue.js enter key and blur events together

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to make it so that if I press enter key or if element loses focus then it hides the element and shows a message. But the problem is that when I press the enter key and the element hides then it also triggers the blur event. It should only execute one of them.

Also how could I avoid having to repeat myself twice by calling the hideField() function. Can I call it only once (bur or key.enter)?

```
<input id="name" v-on:blur="hideField('name')" v-on:keyup.enter="hideField('name')">
```

Here is a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/dag5ch26/3/

Answer (score 39):

You should call the blur method on the keyup.enter event. This results in the blur event being triggered indirectly.

```
<input id="name" v-on:blur="hideField('name')" v-on:keyup.enter="$event.target.blur()">
```

Comment: working for me Perfectly Thanks

Comment: Beautiful solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the limitations of your example, I don't think it is necessary to fire the event on `enter` like you have it. As you see, the `keyup.enter` event also fires the `blurs` event, so why not rely on the `blur` exclusively? I understand you may have simplified your use case, but I don't see a reason for the `keyup.enter` here.

As a side note, instead of selecting the element by ID, you can just use 
`event.target` for the element reference. E.g. `@v-on:blur="hideField"`. The event is passed to `hideField()` automatically. Alternatively, you could do `@v-on:blur="hideField($event.target)"` which would just pass the element itself to the method. This simplifies your call(s) and reduces unnecessary lookups.

I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dag5ch26/7/

Comment: Well, sometimes I'd like to be able to press enter on them as well.

Comment: One alternative solution would be to set some prop on `data` on the `keyup.enter` event to `true` and check if that value was still `true` in the `blur` event. If it's `true` in the `blur` event, just return. I favor this option less because it means you keep track of x number of fields on the page. You would also have to make sure to set the value back to `false` somehow too. (Maybe `setTimeout`? Feels hackey)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe there is a way to do this currently, although a *v-on-many* would be nice in future.

You could bind the event handlers yourself in JavaScript during the *created* life cycle handler.

Something like the below (although IMo this may be worse than your current implementation):

```
Component code {
    ...
    created() {
        window.addEventListener(‘click keyup’, function() {
    this.myComponentMethod(); }
    } }
```